# Digital number counting

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation

Consider all $100$ digit strings, i.e. those between $0$ to $10^{100}-1$ inclusive. For each number, take the product of non-zero digits (treat any zeros as ones), and sum across all the numbers. What’s the last digit?

Is there a mathematical way (i.e. not using excel brute-force calculation) to do this?

Comment: What I know for use is that there is no way of doing it by brute force in less than a couple million years (even less if you use Excel)

Comment: @David this is an easy problem in number theory.

Comment: Kiann: are you treating numbers with fewer than 100 digits as including leading zeros or not?

Comment: treating 100 digits as including leading zeros. i,e, 100 will become 0, 000, ... 100.

Comment: @Kiann, in some sense, according to the problem description it would actually become 1111...100.

Comment: @whuber Please read again my comment. I said "no way of doing it by brute force"

Comment: @David I've dealt with all $2^{101}-1$ from the products that all digits are treated as 1.

Comment: @David That element of your claim was clear from the outset (although a "couple million years" is a gross understatement!).  The strong but incorrect implication that this could be a difficult or intractable problem deserved a comment.

Answer (score 14):

Let $S(n)$ be the specified sum up to $n$ digits. $S(1)=46$, bearing in mind the convention for the zero product, and
$$S(n+1)=S(n)+1S(n)+2S(n)+\dots+9S(n)=46S(n)$$
Thus $S(n)=46^n$, so we need to find the last digit of $46^{100}$. Now if $k$ ends in a $6$, so do all its powers, so the last digit is $6$.